# Linq insert statement inserts nothing, does not fail either

Tags: asp.net, database, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to insert a new account in my Acccounts table with linq. I tried using the EntityModel and Linq2Sql. I get no insert into my database nor an exception of any kind.

```
public static Linq2SQLDataContext dataContext {
        get { return new Linq2SQLDataContext(); }
    }

try {
      //EntityModel
      Accounts acc = Accounts.CreateAccounts(0, Voornaam, Straat, Huisnummer, Stad, Land, 15, EmailReg, Password1);
      Entities.AddToAccounts(acc);
      Entities.SaveChanges();

      //Linq 2 SQL
      Account account = new Account { City = Stad, Country = Land, EmailAddress = EmailReg, Name = Voornaam, Password = Password1, Street = Straat, StreetNr = Huisnummer, StreetNrAdd = Toevoeging, Points = 25 };
      dataContext.Accounts.InsertOnSubmit(account); 

      var conf = dataContext.ChangeConflicts;  // No changeConflicts
      ChangeSet set = dataContext.GetChangeSet(); // 0 inserts, 0 updates, 0 deletes

    try {
        dataContext.SubmitChanges();
    } catch (Exception ex) { }

        } catch (EntityException ex) {          

    }
```

Comment: Have you insert breakpoints into catch block ? (your code suppresses all exceptions)

Comment: Yes, i have put breakpoints in both catch blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was:

```
public static Linq2SQLDataContext dataContext {         get { return new Linq2SQLDataContext(); }     }
```

Which creates a new datacontext every time.
Because of this,

```
dataContext.Accounts.InsertOnSubmit(account);   and
dataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

do not have any reference to each other, because they are 2 different datacontexts which will result in not submitting any query.

Answer (score 4):

You wrap the .SubmitChanges() in a try/catch, but swallow the exception... are you sure no exception is occurring?

Comment: Positive, In debugmode it doesnt enter the catch.

try {     dataContext.SubmitChanges();
} catch (Exception ex) {
          string testt = ex.Message.ToString();
}

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps, but I just had the exact same symptom.

I had the LINQ insert within a transaction.

The cause was an AFTER INSERT trigger which was failing, causing the transaction to not complete, however there was NO exception.

Also using SQL Profiler did not show anything. I only found it by pasting the INSERT statement out of Profiler and running it manually.